# "Colegio" and "Dormitorio"

Tags: false-friend

According to the [mental floss article](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57195/50-spanish-english-false-friend-words), *colegio* and "college" are listed as false friends, and *dormitorio* and "dormitory" are also listed as false friends.

But it contradicts the translations in Google Translate:

- [*collegio* ->  college](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+spanish+to+english+colegio&oq=translate) / [college -> *colegio*](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+english+to+spanish+college&oq=translate)
- [*dormitorio* -> dormitory](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+spanish+to+english+dormitorio&oq=translate) / [dormitory -> *dormitorio*](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+english+to+spanish+dormitory&oq=translate)

I didn't really understand why the above Mental Floss article seems to contradict the translations on Google Translate.

Comment: Mentalfloss is right about those two pairs of words being false friends. The translation they propose is the correct one.

Comment: @Gustavon I usually rely on the translations on Google Translate.

Comment: You should not rely on google translate. It is useful but full of mistakes.

Comment: There are better resources, like [dict.cc](https://enes.dict.cc/), [LEO](https://dict.leo.org/spanish-english/), and for words and phrases in context, [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/).

Comment: @pablodf76 Linguee is an English-German dictionary.

Comment: Google translate is full of mistakes. Please do not use it as an authority for anything at all. Use a real dictionary like the Larousse Spanish<>English dictionaries.

Comment: For Spanish in particular, the **Real Academia Española** (RAE) makes its (highly authoritative) dictionary available online for free. They are an established language academy based out of Spain, and not always the absolute last word in Spanish usage (especially when dealing with Latin American regional usage, highly colloquial terms, etc.), but they are nevertheless one of the most useful places to start. Check their entries on [*colegio*](https://dle.rae.es/colegio) and [*dormitorio*](https://dle.rae.es/dormitorio).

Comment: The terms are somewhat "tricky". "colgeio" is used when referring to something like the electoral college.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google translate is wrong while mentalfloss is right.

- *colegio* = high school / school
- college = *universidad*
- *dormitorio* = bedroom
- dormitory = *residencia universitaria*

In Spanish *colegio* is an educational institution. In some countries it is used for the latest years (high school) but in some others like in Colombia it is used for all grades that come after kinder garden.

I guess the other words don't need much explanation.

Google translate is a useful tool but is full of mistakes.

Comment: Just to complicate things what DGaleano says applies to the US, other varieties of English have different meanings for college and dormitory. A dormitory for me is any communal sleeping place, not necessarily in a university, it could be in a hostel or a boarding school. Some expensive private schools call themselves college although that is not common. Truly international languages pose problems for us all.

Comment: It is common in this site to see questions including "but why Google translate it as x?" I don't keep track but we see that here very often. I'd recommend double checking Google translate with other tools like the one @pablodf76 recommended. You can use the search tool on this site to look for "Google translate" and find more examples

Comment: Another example is "fútbol" which translates to "soccer" or "association football". "football" is called "fútbol americano". However, many people call "association football" or "soccer" as "football".

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya No, in the States people say soccer but in England they say football. So, that's why online stuff does not work.